# WPF Ribbon Window - With No Resize Style

Tags: wpf, user-interface, ribbon

There is a weird border at the bottom of my WPF Ribbon Window.  It only occurs when I set the RibbonWindow's ResizeMode to NoResize.  How do I get rid of the line at the bottom?

[image: The arrows are pointing to the issue]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this right with my version, but I would try to set the ResizeMode to NoResize after the loaded-event of the RibbonWindow. It should ensure that a first layout pass has been done before setting the value.

Comment: Sorry that didn't fix it either.  I am running Windows 7 if that helps.

Comment: Does this happen at any given time when you set the ResizeMode to NoResize? And when you set it back to another value, everything is fine?

Comment: Only when resizemode is NoResize or CanMinimize.  Yes, when I set it back everything is fine.  I looked at the controltemplate of the ribbonwindow, but nothing stood out as a possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `WindowStyle` property of the `RibbonWindow` is set as `SingleBorderWindow`. Hope that helps.